# Homeomorphism between intervals

Tags: analysis, continuity, compactness

If  $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is a continuous bijection and $f^{-1}$ is continuous the $f$ is an homeomorphism. So $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are homeomorphs, i.e. topologically equivalent. (I read it in book)

Can we also say that $f:[c,d] \rightarrow [a,b]$ is an homeomorphism?
My intuition says yes, we can do that because the intervals are topologically equivalent.

Note: [x,y] means a closed interval, so is compact.

Comment: If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ then the map from $[c,d]$ to $[a,b]$ would technically be $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a theorem in Munkres, Chapter 3 26.6, that any continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. So yes, there is a homeomorphism under these conditions. I would recommend you attempt to prove this statement, for practice, before you read the theorem/proof.

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to see that $$f:[a,b]\to [c,d], \,\ f(x)=\frac{c-d}{a-b}x+\frac{ad-bc}{a-b},$$ is a homeomorphism where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq b$.

Comment: Of course it must be $c\neq a$.